# JavaScript:Choose Colour Randomly for a letter based upon input

Tags: javascript

I am writing a application which takes user inputs and assigns randomly the colors to each letter in the text.

HTML CODE

```
<label id="text">
Retrieve data from selected text input among various text inputs with same 
name & id upon hitting Enter
</label>
<div>
<input type="text" id="inputColors">
</div>

<input id="Enter" type="button" value="Enter" />
```

JavaScript

```
 document.getElementById("Enter").onclick = function() {
 var colors = document.getElementById('inputColors').value;
 var colorslist = colors.split(/[;,]+/);


 $('#text').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().split(' ').map(function(v) {
    return '<span style="color:' + colorslist[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
 colorslist.length)] + '">' + v + '</span>';
  }).join(' '));
});
}
```

I am able to color each word but would like it to do it for each letter.I dont want to use css.

Comment: `.split('')` instead of `.split(' ')`, obviously. Same for `.join`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently wraps a `span` around each word because it `splits` the string on the space character.

Instead you should split it using `.split()` which will return an array of all characters (including the spaces).

You then need to join them with nothing too using `.join()`.

```js
document.getElementById("Enter").onclick = function() {
  var colors = document.getElementById('inputColors').value;
  var colorslist = colors.split(/[;,]+/);

  $('#text').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().split('').map(function(v) {
      return '<span style="color:' + colorslist[Math.floor(Math.random() *
        colorslist.length)] + '">' + v + '</span>';
    }).join(''));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  Retrieve data from selected text input among various text inputs with same name &amp; id upon hitting Enter
</div>
<input type="text" id="inputColors" value="red,yellow,blue,green,orange" />
<input id="Enter" type="button" value="Enter" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Do we have a way for chosing random color in such a way that no two letters are in same color?

Comment: You could randomise the colours outside of the map. Then inside of the map iterate through the colours until you reach the end then reset. They wont be random. i.e it will repeat rygbo, rygbo if you want it to be random (i.e ryrgbryo) you'll need to call random inside of the map like you do currently but you'll have to keep a reference to the previous characters colour, if its the same use the next colour.